# How do I receive a subset of data from Kafka?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I know we can filter the data in our consumer/streaming programs. But what I am looking for here is a solution to filter the data from Kafka broker itself.

**Problem Statement**: I have a use case to fetch the whole content of data present in Kafka and also a subset of this data. So when I create a Consumer, I need to pass a filter query so that I will receive only the filtered data.

I have tried to achieve it using Python consumer and Py spark streaming programs. But I couldn't achieve it. I have shared below the code snippet I have tried.

**Python Program**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads
from time import sleep

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'mytopic',
    bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='latest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my-group-id',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
)
for event in consumer:
    event_data = event.value
    # Do whatever you want
    print(event_data)
    sleep(0.5)
```

**Py Spark Program**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField
import json

master="local"
appname="kafka-spark-streaming"


spark = SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(appname).getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092").option("subscribe", "mytopic").option("startingOffsets", "latest").load()
df=df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df.show()
```

In either case, the offset value **latest** will give me the streaming data. and **earliest** will give me the whole data present in Kafka including the streaming data.

Comment: Not possible in the context you sketch.

Comment: @thebluephantom OH! is it? So better to do the filtering after consuming the dataset right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean all / subset of a topic, as in offsets, then you must seek and stop the consumer at the offsets manually.

If you want to filter subsets of each individual record, for both solutions, you need to further *parse your data*.

For example, in plain Python, you would write if statements within your consumer loop based on the content of the data to ignore certain records. In your case, `event.value` should be a dictionary.

Similarly in Spark, you'd need to use a UDF, such as `from_json` to parse your string value column into a further Struct, then you can use `filter` dataframe function, as with any other SparkSQL pipeline

Comment: I understood. But in that case we need to filter the data in the consumer side right ? I don't want to take that overhead. Is there any way we could tell Kafka to do that filtering and give us the filtered dataset?

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not possible with Kafka. Any client needs to read all the topic, then deserialize and post-filter, accordingly.